# How to convert AngularJS to Vue for a JHipster project?

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, jhipster

Although I know AngularJS, I would like to use Vue for my next JHipster project due to its simplicity over AngularJS and Angular 2. I don't get much out of the Vue module. I guess that it is easier to convert a generated AngularJS to Vue instead of starting from scratch. Any suggestions or inputs on this subject?

Comment: To those people who flagged this question, do any of you work with JHipster and a high level of expertise? If you do, you would be able to answer the question as what Gael does. If no, please be respectful to yourself and won't flag a question you don't understand or not be able to answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's your next JHipster project it means you start from scratch so why do you want to convert angular code to Vue?

Just generate the server part and write the client part using adequate Vue tooling.

`yo jhipster --skip-client`

The client part can sit in its own project folder and you can even use another code generator for it.

You could generate your API client from swagger spec exposed by JHipster server using [swagger-vue](https://github.com/chenweiqun/swagger-vue)

**Edit 2019-03-06**

There is now a [JHipster Vue blueprint](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-vuejs) which has been beta released.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will look into it as I am still new to JHipster.

Comment: After testing out the Vue.js CLI, I feel that it is a right approach of separating server and client. One advantage of this approach is that it is easier to build a mobile app because the client code is independent. One possible problem/difficulty, however, is on deployment unless the server and the client are deployed separately. I plan to deploy the application on Google Cloud. To do so, I need to dockerized the application, to my understanding. I don't know how that play out at this moment.

Comment: I forgot to mention the configuration for two separated server and client. Is a way for an auto client configuration so that the client always know where the server is.

Comment: Well,we use webpack-dev-server proxy feature for this, I don't know for Vue